# I am sending raw SES email through node, however this email is not saving in s3 bucket. Should I be expecting it to save a copy in s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I set up SES and using nodeJS to send a simple raw email. I have also verified my email address. The test executes successfully and I get an email few seconds after. However in my S3 bucket, I am not seeing a copy of this email. Should I be expecting a copy to be saved in S3 bucket? or is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get a copy stored automatically. You can use CloudWatch logs to store the API requests, or if you need to store the contents directly including things like attachments, the best option is to create an [S3 Action for SES](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-s3.html) and then send a copy of the message to an email address tied to this action.

Comment: I have already setup an S3 action for my SES. Object prefix is Email. no encryption checked, and no sns topic. Am I missing some kind of rule/policy to save?

Comment: The S3 action is for receiving email. You need to send the email to an address connected to the action. It won't automatically capture emails sent from SES, only emails received by SES

Comment: how do i go about connecting an address to the action? I verified the email in ses, but if this is a separate step not sure how to proceed

Comment: Add a receipt rule in SES. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-receipt-rules.html